# Targeting specific objects in jsonb array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I need to select rows from table that match specific criteria which involves jsonb object field comparison.

In the example below, I'd like to get only rows for which a value is within a min/max range as specified by an object from array: for any given row if any object from its `array_of_objects` "contains" (using min/max comparison) a `value`, I need that row.

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
  id serial,
  value int,
  array_of_objects jsonb[]
);

INSERT INTO
  test_table (value, array_of_objects)
VALUES
  (8, ARRAY ['{"min":5,"max":15}', '{"min":4,"max":18}']::jsonb[]),
  (6, ARRAY ['{"min":12,"max":18}', '{"min":19,"max":22}']::jsonb[]),
  (22, ARRAY ['{"min":16,"max":18}', '{"min":34,"max":47}']::jsonb[]);
```

So for given example I'd get only rows with values `8` and `22`.

Comment: mx:18 less then 22, so why 22 here as well? and you have the condition to be aplied for all elements of array?..

Comment: look at my answer - if I apply min < value< max to all elements of array for "value" column, I get rows only for value=8. and the resultset you want is not clear - do you want array_of_objects or rows with jsonb[] values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want original columns:

```
t=# with a as (select unnest(array_of_objects) j,* from test_table)
select distinct id,value, array_of_objects
from a
where (j->>'min')::int < value and (j->>'max')::int > value;
 id | value |                     array_of_objects
----+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------
  1 |     8 | {"{\"max\": 15, \"min\": 5}","{\"max\": 18, \"min\": 4}"}
(1 row)
```

and here is "explanation" why value 22 did not get into it (array_of_objects[1]->>max is less then 22:

```
Time: 0.441 ms
t=# with a as (select unnest(array_of_objects) j,* from test_table)
select distinct id,value,j
from a
where (j->>'min')::int < value and (j->>'max')::int > value;
 id | value |           j
----+-------+-----------------------
  1 |     8 | {"max": 18, "min": 4}
  1 |     8 | {"max": 15, "min": 5}
(2 rows)

Time: 0.390 ms
```

Comment: thank you! The fact that you return a single row – makes sense. I made a mistake when writing the question down.

Comment: Do you think there'd be more efficient way to search jsonb nested arrays like this? it _feels_ like duplicating rows via unnest may be a little slow?

Comment: Don't think so - any way you have to nest array elements for comparison. one by one

Answer (score 0):

It will be possible to avoid using `unnest` sometime after PostgreSQL 10.

There's a [PR](https://commitfest.postgresql.org/13/1063/) in PostgreSQL Commitfest implementing a huge chunk of JSON-related functions, standardised as part of the latest [SQL 2016](https://www.iso.org/standard/63556.html) standard:

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  title VARCHAR,
  number INTEGER,
  my_array JSONB
);

INSERT INTO my_table (title, number, my_array) VALUES
  ('not expected', 6, '[{"min": 1, "max": 5}, {"min": 7, "max": 10}]'::JSONB),
  ('expected', 7, '[{"min": 1, "max": 5}, {"min": 7, "max": 10}]'::JSONB);

SELECT *
  FROM my_table
 WHERE JSON_EXISTS(my_array, '$[*] ? (@.min < $x && $x <= @.max)' PASSING number AS x);
```